# Select all data WHERE x = $_SESSION value

Tags: php, mysql, session, pdo

Since I have already posted this and some people discarded my question as a "duplicate" without actually answering it (the page where they told me to look wasn't relevant), and I still can't get any answer, here it is, again...

I would like a page to display all results corresponding with a `id_slogan` that was set randomly on a previous page. So on the first page, a random info from the DB `liste_slogans` is generated, and its id is kept in a `$_SESSION` variable. On each on the three different pages involved, I start the session and I only destroy it at the end of the last one. In short, the first page is where the visitor interacts with the website by entering data, the second processes it and then redirects to the last page with a data list that is supposed to be linked to the information on the first page. Here's some code from the first one :

```
<?php
    $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slogans', 'root', 'root', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
    $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT id, slogan, compagnie FROM liste_slogans ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1,1');
    header("Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

    while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
    {
        echo '<p class="apparition1" element style="color:aqua">' . ($donnees['slogan']) . ' <element style="color:transparent">' . ($donnees['id']) . '' . ($donnees['compagnie']) . '</element style></p>';
        $_SESSION['id_slogan']=$donnees['id'];
        $_SESSION['compagnie']=$donnees['compagnie'];
        $_SESSION['slogan']=$donnees['slogan']; 
    }                   
?>
```

On the last page, I want to display all the entries in the DB `entrees` which have a `id_slogan` matching with the session variable set on the first page (`$_SESSION['id_slogan']`). I have tried this and many other things, but nothing seems to work :

```
<?php
    try
    {
        $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slogans;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
    }   

    $nbid = $_SESSION['id_slogan'];
    $reponse=$bdd->query('SELECT pseudo, entree, id_slogan FROM entrees WHERE id_slogan = '.$nbid' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 50');

    while ($donnees=$reponse->fetch())
    {
        echo '<h4 class=resultats><strong>' . htmlspecialchars($donnees['entree']) . ' </strong></h4> <p class=resultats> ' . htmlspecialchars($donnees['pseudo']) . '</p>';
    }
    $reponse->closeCursor();
?>
```

Could anyone please help me with this? I've spent hours searching on the internet but can't seem to find any answer...

Edit : I guess I should show all my code...

There's the first page :

```
    <?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Pubweb1.css"/>
        <title>(re)trouver le sens</title>
        <!--[if It IE9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html15.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

    <div class="tout">  
    <body>
    <!--[if IE 6]><body class="ie6 old_ie"><!--[endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]><body class="ie7 old_ie"><!--[endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]><body class="ie8"><!--[endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]><body class="ie9"><!--[endif]-->
    <!--[if ! IE]><body><!--><!--[endif]-->

    <div class="barredef">
        <?php include("barredef.php");?>
    </div>

    <div class="blocpage">
        <header>
            <?php include("menu1.php");?>
        </header>



        <!-- Affichage aléatoire d'une donnée de la table et enregistrement des infos ID, slogan et compagnie -->
        <section>
            <?php
                $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slogans', 'root', 'root', array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
                $reponse = $bdd->query('SELECT ID, slogan, compagnie FROM liste_slogans ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1,1');
                header("Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8");

                while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
                {
                    echo '<p class="apparition1" element style="color:aqua">' . ($donnees['slogan']) . ' <element style="color:transparent">' . ($donnees['ID']) . '' . ($donnees['compagnie']) . '</element style></p>';
                    $_SESSION['id_slogan']=$donnees['ID'];
                    $_SESSION['compagnie']=$donnees['compagnie'];
                    $_SESSION['slogan']=$donnees['slogan']; 
                }   
                $nbid = $_SESSION['id_slogan'];             
            ?>
            <h2 class=apparition1>(À vous de jouer...)</h2>
            <!-- Il faut que le slogan qui apparaît ait une entrée au moins -->
        </section>

        <section>
            <br/><h6>Entrez votre question, votre idée, votre doute.<br/>
            Remettez en question l'énoncé publicitaire présenté.<br/>
            Gardez en tête ce que les mots signifient vraiment pour vous, et exprimez-le si vous le jugez pertinent.<br/>
            Pas inspiré(e)? Cliquez sur "Sélection aléatoire" dans le menu ci-haut.</h6>
        <form action='redirection.php' method='POST'> 
            <p><input type="text" name="entree" id="entree" size="75" maxlenght="300" autofocus />
            <label for='pseudo'><h6>Votre signature : </h6></label><input type="text" name="pseudo" id="pseudo" size="75" maxlenght="30" /><br/>
            <input type='hidden' name="id_slogan" id="id_slogan" size="40" maxlenght="4" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id_slogan'];?>" />
            <input type='hidden' name="compagnie" id="compagnie" size="40" maxlenght="4" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['compagnie'];?>" /><br/><br/>
            <input class="envoiemail" name="submit" type="submit" value="Soumettre"></p>
        </form>

            <?php
        // Connexion à la base de données
            try
            {
                $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slogans;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
            }

            $reponse->closeCursor();
            ?>
        </section>
        </div>
    </body>
        </div>

</html
```

There's the processing/redirection page :

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
?>
<?php
//Connexion à la base de données
    try
    {
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slogans;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
    }   
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        die('Erreur : '. $e->getMessage());
    }

// Insertion de l'entrée à l'aide d'une requête préparée
    $req=$bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO entrees (pseudo, entree, date_entree, id_slogan) VALUES (?, ?, NOW(), ?)');
    $req->execute(array($_POST['pseudo'], $_POST['entree'], $_POST['id_slogan']));

//Redirection du visiteur vers la page des résultats
    header('Location: resultats.php');
?>
```

And there's the last one :

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Pubweb1.css"/>
        <title>(re)trouver le sens</title>
        <!--[if It IE9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html15.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>

        <div class="tout">  
    <div class="blocpage">
    <body>
    <!--[if IE 6]><body class="ie6 old_ie"><!--[endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]><body class="ie7 old_ie"><!--[endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]><body class="ie8"><!--[endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]><body class="ie9"><!--[endif]-->
    <!--[if ! IE]><body><!--><!--[endif]-->

        <header>
            <?php include("menu1.php");?>   
        </header>

        <section>
            <h1><?php echo $_SESSION['slogan']; 
            $nbid = $_SESSION['id_slogan']; ?></h1>
        </section>

        <section>
            <p class=boutonsuivant><a href=aleatoire.php>Suivant</a></p>
            <p class=compagnie><?php echo $_SESSION['compagnie']; ?></p>
            <p class=boutonnav><a href=slogan1.php>Naviguer</a></p>
        </section>

        <p>Numéro : <?php echo $_SESSION['id_slogan']; ?>.</p>

        <section>
        <?php
// Connexion à la base de données
        try
        {
            $bdd=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=slogans;charset=utf8', 'root', 'root');
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
        }   

// Récupération des derniers messages
        $reponse=$bdd->query('SELECT pseudo, entree, id_slogan FROM entrees WHERE id_slogan = $nbid ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 50');
        $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Affichage de chaque message (toutes les données sont protégées par htmlspecialchrs)
        while ($donnees=$reponse->fetch())
        {
            echo '<h4 class=resultats><strong>' . htmlspecialchars($donnees['entree']) . ' </strong></h4> <p class=resultats> ' . htmlspecialchars($donnees['pseudo']) . '</p>';
        }
        $reponse->closeCursor();
        ?>  

        <?php
        session_destroy();
        ?>
        </section>

    </body>
    </div>
    </div>
</html
```

Comment: Firstly, did you start the session?

Comment: are your sure your database is returning something? See what you get if you mock out the database.

Comment: Fred : Yes, it is written above : I start the session on every page.

Comment: DudeOnRock : What do you mean mock ou the database? When put like above the page is totally blank ; with anything else I tried it returns everything in my database, which is not what I want.

Comment: I see a number of potential issues. Let's start with your 2nd SQL Query: `'SELECT pseudo, entree FROM entrees WHERE id_slogan = '.$nbid' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 0, 50'`, this is missing concatenation.

Comment: Replace the database with a replacement you know will return a result for testing purposes

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` You have several syntax errors.

Comment: Also, how I know this community, it is never a good idea to start a question by stating that you are just reposting a question because your first one was closed.

Comment: Hmm I can get results easily with that one, but I think my PDO request isn't written well, it's only when I modify that that it displays nothing at all

Comment: `'.$nbid'` that's a syntax error.  Use http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and error reporting, as already outlined by @JayBlanchard - Probably why your code is failing.

Comment: Sorry... I'll know better next time

Comment: Fred : I guess so... but that's exactly what I'm trying to figure out, how to write it in a correct way

Comment: Twisty : What would be correct?

Comment: Modify it to `WHERE id_slogan = '$nbid'` - It shouldn't really matter if that's an integer or not.  If it's an integer though `WHERE id_slogan = $nbid`, but if it's a string `WHERE id_slogan = '".$nbid."'` where you made the same syntax error in your other question.

Comment: @Patricia, Fred has already pointed out how to address this.

Comment: It sounds like you are very new to PHP. I would suggest you follow a tutorial that includes MySQL (https://www.codecademy.com/ is very good) or your experience with PHP will be very frustrating.

Comment: DudeOnRock : Yes, all I know I've learned by myself on the Internet... and yes it is very frustrating. I'll check that website, I've tried Fred's suggestions but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: What I find hard to find is information on how to play with MySQL queries AND session values, both are always presented seperately

Comment: Your database might be case-sensitive. You're selecting `id` in one query, then using `ORDER BY ID` in uppercase `ID`. However, you're querying this table `FROM liste_slogans` in one, then querying `FROM entrees` in another. Check for errors as already stated and check to see if the session is set/not empty.

Comment: Addendum to the above: If both ID's don't match from both tables, then your query failed.

Comment: Fred : There doesn't seem to be any error as long as I don't add 'WHERE id_slogan = $nbid' to my second query... I changed it just in case, but it really seems to be all about that bit.

Comment: *"On each on the three different pages involved"* - You showed us what seems to only be 2 here. You'll need to edit your question to include your db schema for all those tables. Apply this to all your pages `if(isset($_SESSION['id_slogan']) && !empty($_SESSION['id_slogan'])) { your code here }`

Comment: However, I see that you haven't selected the `id` column or `id_slogan` in `SELECT pseudo, entree FROM entrees` - I think that may be the clincher here. Try adding it in your query. I'm out of ideas at this point.

Comment: Is there other PHP code on the page that we can't see? I'm questioning this because it doesn't appear you're calling `session_start()` ?

Comment: and this `</element style>` should "style" be in there? I kind of doubt it. Anyways Patricia, I wish you all the best with this one. I sincerely hope you can resolve this. I won't be able to offer any more help on this one; good luck. If it's of any comfort, I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: by the way, you edited your question with `session_start();` in one body of code, but it's not shown in the other ones. If `session_start();` isn't inside the other ones, then there's your problem. If it is in them, you should add it in there. `session_start();` is required to be inside all files using sessions.

Comment: Thank you a lot Fred... Most of the problem is probably my lack of knowledge actually :P

Comment: Jojunol : Yes, there is much code you can't see, I was afraid it would be too much and irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, the session start is included everywhere.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, you also have a missing semi-colon here `header('Location: resultats.php')` if that's your actual code. That will break your code.

Comment: Potricia: If you haven't added error reporting (mentioned before), I would suggest you do so as it will point out where the errors are coming from. Also try adding (under the new PDO(....)) `$bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Comment: Jojunol : Yes that's a weird thing I have never understood : I use this in my code (in the present case I had forgotten) but when there's an error the page generated is totally blank (white), and there no way I can get error codes on Safari nor Firefox. But I can't say I have tried very hard to resolve that problem, I've been more focused on what's up here.

Comment: Completely blank? If you add `echo "Hello world!";` does it show up? I'm starting to get the feeling your service isn't started properly

Comment: Hmm I guess it is better if I show all the code...

Comment: Hmmm I was hoping that `error_reporting` or pdo errmode would provide of some guidance of where the error may be but unfortunately not. I'm assuming that your HTTP server service(like apache), PHP service as well as your MySQL service are all currently running ? Other than that, I too am out of ideas.

Comment: Yes, Apache and MySQL are running... thank you for trying :P seems like everyone is out of ideas, but if I ever find the answer I'll post it

Answer (score 0):

There's the answer :

```
   $nbid = isset( $_SESSION['id_slogan'] ) ?  $_SESSION['id_slogan'] : NULL;
    if($nbid){
    $sql = "SELECT pseudo, entree, id_slogan 
               FROM entrees 
               WHERE id_slogan = $nbid 
               ORDER BY ID DESC 
               LIMIT 0, 50";

     $reponse=$bdd->query($sql);
      $bdd->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
```